# No puedo descargar tablas como excel

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, maven

La cosa es simple, quiero exportar una tabla de primefaces a .xlsx sin embargo al momento de presionar el botón que debería hacerlo, me sale la siguiente excepción :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.RichTextString
```

Es como si no detectará apache poi, sin embargo sí lo tengo instalado.

Esta es la imagen de mi vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo de mi vista:

```
<h:form prependId="false" id="listadoUsuarios">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s2">
                <h:commandLink class="btn">
                    Exportaaaaar
                    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="listadoUsuarios" fileName="ok" pageOnly="true"/>
                </h:commandLink>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <p:dataTable value="#{userController.allUsers}" var="u">
                    <p:column headerText="Nombre" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{u.name}" sortBy="#{u.name}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{u.name}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Email" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{u.email}" sortBy="#{u.email}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{u.email}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Teléfono" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{u.phone}" sortBy="#{u.phone}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{u.phone}"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:form>
```

El codigo de mi pom.xml en el web donde tengo apache-poi:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.2-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
        <version>6.0</version>  
    </dependency>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme a lograrlo :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues bien, después de tanto pelear con maven, resulta que se debe instalar pero desde el pom del EJB Aunque realmente no entiendo el por qué, pues todo ocurre dentro del entorno web,pero así es.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.2-FINAL</version>
</dependency>
```